# ASP.Net website not rendering correctly on client

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have deployed a ASP.net website and for whatever reason the website is rendering like it should on the web server, but when i access it from a client some of the formatting is lost, so for instance the menu items disappear from the menu, i am at a loss as to where to begin as the website is functional, it just isn't rendering how it should, i suspect that it might have something to do with CSS, but really not sure.

I have tried to make remove some reference to bundles and called the style sheets directly using link with no difference.

I have checked i am able to access the site.css from a client too.

Having looked a bit further into it, IE is returning the following two errors:

> **SCRIPT5007**: Unable to get property 'createElement' of undefined or
>   null reference jquery-3.3.1.min.js (2,6997)
>
> **SCRIPT5022**: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery bootstrap.min.js
>   (6,31)

Comment: can you open a Chrome Developer Tools on that page, take snapshot of Network tab and post it to your question. Thnx.

Comment: hmm, that is strange, it renders fine in Chrome, just not working in IE

Comment: IE has different rendering modes that can be utilized. You can read about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the mime type registered on iis? It could be possible that the response for the css request could have a different mime type than what the browser expected and thus did not parse it/apply the style rules.
To check/fix this, open server manager -> browse to your site. In the IIS settings panel would be Mime types, ensure that text/css is the MIME Type for the `.css` extension, also in your link tag try including `type="text/css"` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, managed to figure it out, the issue was there was a GPO setting that was ticked to display intranet sites in compatibility mode, i unchecked this and it began to work as expected, hope this helps someone else.